# How to remove items from woocommerce cart upon adding other items

Tags: php, woocommerce

How to get an order bump to go in place of the current product?

I sell ebooks (4 of them) and when someone adds 1 of the 4 ebooks to the cart I want the order bump in the cart to show bundles that give a discount. No problem here, that works.

Here's the question: when someone decides to take the bundle offer, the single book should disappear automatically from the cart.

I have 2 bundles, 1 of 4 ebooks together, 1 of 3 ebooks together

So when the 4 book bundle is added as order bump, all 4 ebooks plus the 3 book bundle (if present in the cart) should disappear from the cart

And when the 3 book bundle is added, all 3 individual ebooks should disappear from the cart (if present)

The code below works for 1 target item and 1 to remove item, how can I extend it for the case above?

```
<?php 
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'check_product_added_to_cart', 10, 6 );
function check_product_added_to_cart($cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $c
art_item_data) {
    // Set HERE your targeted product ID
    $target_product_id = 2754;//I need to check agains 2 bundles, 2754,2752
    // Set HERE the  product ID to remove
    $item_id_to_remove = 902;//For the 4 book bundle this is an array of 4 individual books (902,910,915,917) plus the 3 book bundle (2752) and for the 3 book bundle this should be an array of of 3 individual books (902,910,915)
    // Initialising some variables
    $has_item = false;
    $is_product_id = false;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key => $item ){
        // Check if the item to remove is in cart
        if( $item['product_id'] == $item_id_to_remove ){
            $has_item = true;
            $key_to_remove = $key;
        }
        // Check if we add to cart the targeted product ID
        if( $product_id == $target_product_id ){
            $is_product_id = true;
        }
    }
    if( $has_item && $is_product_id ){
        WC()->cart->remove_cart_item($key_to_remove);
        // Optionaly displaying a notice for the removed item:
        //wc_add_notice( __( 'The product "blab bla" has been removed from cart.', 'theme_domain' ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

The code works for 1 target item and 1 item to remove, now it needs extending with loops for each item as described in the use case